# how to run this rake task with 2 args and environment in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, runtime-error

Here are the first few lines of my rake task:

```
 desc "Import National Data into DB\n Usage: 
 rake import_regional[/Users/am/0925/xyz.csv, some_market]"

 task :import_regional, [:file_path, :market] => [:environment] do |t, args|

 .......
```

Here is how Im trying to run this task on the command line:

```
 rake import_regional ["/Users/xyz.csv", "northeast"]
```

when I try this, I get this error

```
 rake aborted!
 Don't know how to build task 
 'import_regional[/Users/xyz.csv,'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's the way in which you're running the task on the command-line; the `[]` doesn't have its Ruby meaning, there. Instead, maybe see if this works for you:

```
rake "import_regional[/Users/xyz.csv, northeast]"
```

This should still allow for spaces, etc. in `:file_path`, if required.

Peace,
tiredpixel

Answer (score 0):

Command line isn't a Ruby interpreter, it's mangling things before it gets to Rake.

Try this:

```
rake "import_regional['/Users/xyz.csv', 'northeast']"
```